# Как пишется "не()обязательно" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, наречия

В предложении: "Отправить посылку может любой человек, имя менять не обязательно." Корректно ли написано "не обязательно"?

Answer (score 3):

Если обратиться Розенталю, то он рекомендовал опираться на смысл:

> 5. Слова категории состояния на -о (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей **не** слитно при утверждении: *нетрудно* видеть и раздельно при отрицании: *не трудно видеть* (смысл обычно устанавливается самим пишущим).
>
> *Не обязательно, чтобы ответ был дан немедленно.*
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81

В контексте нашего предложения просматривается смысл *отрицания*: человек хотел отправить посылку от имени другого отправителя и поинтересовался, можно так написать на бланке или необходимо изменить имя на своё. Ему отвечают, что **нет** такой необходимости - **не обязательно** указывать имя фактического отправителя (*как это можно подумать*). Речь идёт о конкретном случае (обязательно ли человеку изменить имя на своё), а не об инструкции, *утверждающей* факультативность, необязательность "замены имён". Соответственно, я бы выбрал здесь *раздельное* написание.

Материал, посвящённый конкретно слову "не(_)обязательно":

http://gramatik.ru/neobyazatelno-ili-ne-obyazatelno-slitno-ili-razdelno/

Comment: Смысловое решение орфограммы по Розенталю  определяется по ситуации. Если  это  реальный диалог (Обязательно? - Нет, не обязательно), то написание раздельное (отрицательная конструкция).  Однако в данном случае это похоже на простое сообщение, поэтому используется утверждение. Также позиция предикативного наречия в конце предложения для раздельного написания неудобна. Логического выделения слова в конце фразы нет, отрицание не подчеркнуто, а тогда зачем оно. Лучше использовать утвердительный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Хотя существуют две формы письма, я бы написала слитно: *Отправить посылку может любой человек, имя менять **необязательно**.*

Пояснение

1. Если судить по ситуации, то это скорее частный случай, который не каждый раз встречается.    Поэтому и не обозначается выбор в такой форме: менять обязательно/не обязательно.
2. Если же судить по структуре предложения, то  также лучше выбрать слитное написание.

Обычно при раздельном письме на  слово с НЕ падает логическое ударение, при этом оно чаще стоит в начале фонетической фразы, например: *Отправить посылку может любой человек, не обязательно менять имя.*

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать ***и раздельно, и слитно***. Смысловые нюансы при этом только немного разные.

При раздельном написании **отрицается действие** по глаголу "менять", можно заменить на *имя менять не **надо**.*

При слитном написании получается одно сказуемое *необязательно,* при этом **утверждается необязательность действия** по глаголу "менять".

Ещё хочу обратить ваше внимание на то, что точка всегда ставится **после** закрывающих кавычек.